# Postscript: watermark with varying page sizes

Tags: ghostscript, watermark, postscript

I am trying to use postscript to watermark postscript files. I am doing this with setpagedevice like so:

```
    <<
       /EndPage {
       exch pop 2 lt {
          /Times-Roman 40 selectfont
          .6 setgray 300 300 moveto 30 rotate (Watermark) show
          true}
          {false} ifelse
       } bind
    >> setpagedevice

    (file_to_watermark.ps) run
```

This works great, but I would like the watermark to be centered on the page, regardless of page size (this code needs to work for varying sizes of file_to_watermark.ps). My code right now is positioning the watermark based on specific coordinates, which obviously doesn't center the mark if a different file_to_watermark.ps is used with a different page size (i.e. legal, letter, etc.). Is there someway to retrieve the page size of the current file_to_watermark.ps and center-on-page the watermark based on that rather than predefined coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the current media size from the pagedevice dictionary:

```
currentpagedevice /PageSize get
```

which returns the width and height (in points) on the stack. You can then use the `stringwidth` operator to calculate the amount of space occupied by the given string when printed. There's no simple way to get the vertical height, but the pointsize is as good a guide as anything for Latin fonts.

Subtracting the string width from the page width and dividing by two should be good enough, similarly for the y co-ordinate.

For real printers, instead of using the `MediaSize` the initial clip is sometimes a better bet:

```
initclip clippath flattenpath pathbbox
```