# Add page numbers to combined PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, ghostscript

I am combining several pages into one file using ghostscript.

How (if possible) can I use ghostscript to add pagenumbers to the combined file?

Answer (score 0):

Because the Ghostscript PDF interpreter is written in PostScript you could define a PostScript EndPage procedure to do so.

See:
[PDF crop even-odd pages with PHP + GhostScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413904/pdf-crop-even-odd-pages-with-php-ghostscript/30426517#30426517)

and:
[Postscript: watermark with varying page sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966106/postscript-watermark-with-varying-page-sizes)

for examples of EndPage procedures